# Unable to use Response.Status.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED in Neo4J 2.3.1

Tags: neo4j, jersey, jax-rs, graph-databases

I am creating a REST api with a dynamic path like this:

```java
@DELETE
@Path("/{path: .+}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void delete() {
...
}
```

When I do not find a single node by the path I would like to return a 405 "Method not allowed" response. To do this I tried this:

```java
return Response.status(Response.Status.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED).build();
```

This result in an exception and the server gives a 500 "Server Error" response. This is what I get:

```java
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED
        ... my boring classes...
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.mapException(ContainerResponse.java:480)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.mapMappableContainerException(ContainerResponse.java:417)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1477)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:800)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
        at org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CollectUserAgentFilter.doFilter(CollectUserAgentFilter.java:69)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1125)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1059)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:248)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:540)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any ideas? :)

Comment: Here's [Response.Status for JAX-RS 1.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.Status.html) and here's for [JAX-RS 2.0](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.Status.html). 1.1 doesn't have the field. Has to be a bad mix of versions. I don't use Neo4J, so I am not sure about how to fix the incompatibility

Comment: Did you try `return Response.status(405).build();`?

Comment: @WilliamLyon: Yes I tried it and it works. It feels more like a workaround than a solution. Also when I am calling the method from postman it says "405 ok". Where does the "ok" come from?

Comment: I'd be more concerned with why you are getting this error. If you are getting it now, then you will most likely get it again. You need to rid yourself of the incompatible version combinations. As a hint, it looks like Jersey 1.x is being used, which is JAX-1.1, while the Response.Status class you are trying to use is from JAX-RS 2.0

Answer (score 0):

METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED should just be int 405. So william-lyon's response should be the correct one:

```
return Response.status(405).build();
```

But it looks like we should request neo4j 3.0 upgrade jax-rs to 2 from 1.1.

Can you please create raise an issue on github? https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues